# How do i redirect a li a href link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the user clicks the li link, i want the user to get redirected to #gameshowintro .

Html code:

```
<li class="about"><a href="#gameshowintro"></a></li>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("body").css("display", "none");

    $("body").fadeIn(2000);

    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }

});
```

Comment: Do you wanna get redirected or scrolled to that place?

Comment: I want it redirected, with a fadeout effect.

Comment: Isn't it not in the same page?

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work, you need to pass the `linkLocation` to the function. The `linkLocation` is **not** a **global scope** variable (it is local to the `click` event handler function), which isn't accessible from the called function. So change your code to:

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $("body").fadeOut(1000, "redirectPage('" + linkLocation + "')");
});

function redirectPage(linkLocation) {
    window.location = linkLocation;
}
```

---

Or if you need to scrolled to that section. If that's the case, use this *smooth scroll*:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @JacquesMarais Updated the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: You don't need to pass `linkLocation` to the function, a variable set without the `var` keyword is always global, and the function is run after the variable is set.

Comment: @JacquesMarais Check the code again. It has a local scope. Please!